# Calling rest API thread safely

Tags: rest, api, web-services, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm calling a third party upload document rest API from my spring controller, and I'm passing some fields in the request to the API where the upload document API returns a response, but that response doesn't have any of the values which I had passed to it.

I need to update my database with the response received.
In Single threaded mode it's OK, but how should I save it in case of concurrent access as sometimes it may be like one response may get saved for another user.

The third party API is rejecting to send back any of the values I pass in the request.

Because it's an official system, I can't provide any code.
But still, we are using a REST template to call the API which will have request parameters like `user id`, `request number`, and `file` as a byte array. And the response that we get is just the file name, and the status as doc upload successful. So when accessed concurrently, it can happen that the status and filename that we get in response will be saved against some other user.

Please advise how can I make my code thread safe as the rest API doesn't send any of the values in response.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I incorporated additional information from the comment section.

Comment: Any advices /suggestions?

Comment: Hi folks, any guidance on this issue pls